# How to search or find whether a user is a member of a group or not using LDAP query?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I have a LDAP hierarchy base like `dc=domain,dc=myCompany,dc=com`.
It has two organizational units like Groups and People. I have two groups like group1 and group2.

How can I find whether a user/member with the given distinguished name(`dn`) is a member of a group or not?

Answer (score 1):

Query with a base=cn=group1,ou=groups,dc=yourdomain,dc=com and a filter like:

```
(member=cn=username,dc=yourdomain,dc=com)
```

should get you started.

For checking if the user could also be a member of the group from other nested groups, use a filter like:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=UserName,CN=Users,dc=yourdomain,dc=com))
```

-jim

Comment: The magical number used is the OID for LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN . More info on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28VS.85%29.aspx